# Delphi Split-Merge String without seperators?

Tags: string, algorithm, delphi

Hello I m working about string split-merge like this:

```
Button1.click...etc.
var
s:String;
ars:array[1..10] of String;
i:integer;
begin
ars[1]:='0';
ars[2]:='012';
ars[3]:='23';
ars[4]:='458';
ars[5]:='022'; // These values are example of.
ars[6]:='001';
ars[7]:='0125';
ars[8]:='250';
ars[9]:='859';
ars[10]:='9';

 for i:=1 to 10 do
begin

   s:=s+ars[i];

end;
//Finally I get string like this example: '01123641054257867420..etc..'
end;
```

How can I split the final string back?  I dont know the Length of the ars array value. As you see some of it 4 bytes, 3 bytes, 2 bytes.. I merge all of it and then I want to split it again.. How can I do this? Is there any idea or Algorithms? I searched in Google but I did not anything.. Thank you..

---

@Jens Borrisholt My codes are:

```
unit Unit1;

interface



uses
  Windows, Messages, SysUtils, Variants, Classes, Graphics, Controls, Forms,
  Dialogs, StdCtrls;

type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    Button1: TButton;



  private
    { Private declarations }
  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;

var
  Form1: TForm1;

implementation

{ TMyStrings }
{$R *.dfm}



type TMyStrings = class(TStringList)
  protected
    function GetTextStr: string; override;
  end;

function TMyStrings.GetTextStr: string;
var
  Element: String;
begin
  Result := '';
  for Element in Self do
    Result := Result + Element;
end;

end.
```

Where is the problem?

Comment: Use separators to delimit values

Comment: How can you split the string "abcdefghijklmno" back to the original parts without knowledge of where to split? You have to store the length of each part or use a delimiter

Comment: I can not use seperators. Without seperators.

Comment: Sir Rufo, So I m asking to you. Maybe there is an algorithm or method or idea thetas I dont know?

Comment: When you do "s:=s+ars[i];", the result contains no information as to the strings it is built from, in the sense that there is a large number of different vales for the ars[] contents which would produce the identical result: per se it is not a reversible transformation. So, if you need to recover that info later, you need to store it, or some equivalent, somewhere. Retaining the ars[] array is one method, and it makes no difference to the principle involved if you dress the implementation up as a TStringlist descendant.

Comment: This question is bizarre, because the accepted answer doesn't meet the specified constraints

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no built-in functionality to do that, since you throw away information (the length of each string). So that information have to be stored somewhere.

You could use a TStringList descendant :

**Interface**

```
  TMyStrings = class(TStringList)
  protected
    function GetTextStr: string; override;
  end;
```

**Implementation**

```
{ TMyStrings }

function TMyStrings.GetTextStr: string;
var
  Element: String;
begin
  Result := '';
  for Element in Self do
    Result := Result + Element;
end;
```

And how to use it :

```
procedure TForm5.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
var
  MyStrings : TMyStrings;
begin
  MyStrings := TMyStrings.Create;

  MyStrings.Add('0');
  MyStrings.Add('012');
  MyStrings.Add('23');
  MyStrings.Add('458');
  MyStrings.Add('022'); // These values are example of.
  MyStrings.Add('001');
  MyStrings.Add('0125');
  MyStrings.Add('250');
  MyStrings.Add('859');
  MyStrings.Add('9');

  Caption := MyStrings.Text;
  FreeAndNil(MyStrings);
end;
```

With this in hand you can get your list as a joined string, and you still have the original information about each string.

Comment: 1 <= Length of Strings <= 16

Comment: Yes you can yuo can just ask for MyStrings[3] and you still have access to element #4

Comment: Can I use xor? How can ı do it ?

Comment: Where ı write this code. I wrote first code under Interface, I see error. I wrote second codes under Implementation I see error. Where will I write this codes. thank you.

Comment: If you write it all under ijmplementation and add **type** before TMyStrings  then you are up and running

Comment: I did but I see; Incompatible "Booleadn" and "String". ım using Delphi 7. ANd I see "operator not applicable this operand type" error.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/61629/discussion-between-user872002-and-jens-borrisholt).

Comment: What's the benefit of doing this over just keeping the original array around to reference for the length of each element? You'll still have the "original information about each string" in the array, you can write a simple function that returns the concatenated string, and you don't have to create and free an object instance or add the overhead of all of the functionality in TStrings that you're not using anywhere.

Comment: The only answer to the question is that what is asked for is impossible